# Spring AMQP: How to register a user-defined SpEL function?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Due to the [Spring Expression Language Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#expressions-ref-functions) it's possible to register user-defined funtions which can be used in expressions.

How can I register such a function in the context of Spring AMQP in order to determine a queue name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not fully clear in what context you'd like to determine that queue, but I believe the answer for you is still going to be that it is not possible to customize an internal `EvaluationContext` used in the framework for SpEL parts of configuration. As a workaround you can use a `T` operator for your `static` methods to call. Essentially those SpEL-functions are wrappers around static methods.

Comment: I want to use it in @ QueueBinding / @ Queue.

I am aware of the T operator, but I wanted to make the expression a little bit smaller by introducing custom functions.

Comment: Well, those can use bean references: `@Queue("#{myBean.resolveQueueName()}")`. It is very close to your SpEL-function expectations.

Comment: I agree, seems to be the best solution. Thanks.